# Obtener valor que devuelve una función JS desde el CodeBehind ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Estoy haciendo un formulario en ASP.NET simple, lo único que hace es pedir datos para almacenarlos.
Lo que quiero es que al presionar el botón **"Guardar"** me salga el modal siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual es de una galería llamada SweetAlert. La cual ejecuto con este código:

```
function preguntar(){
  const swalWithBootstrapButtons = Swal.mixin({
  confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
  cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
  buttonsStyling: false,
})

swalWithBootstrapButtons({
  title: 'Desea guardar los registros?',
  text: "No podra cancelar la operacion",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, Guardar',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancelar!',
  reverseButtons: true
 }).then((result) => {

 if (result.value) {
   return true
 } else if (
  // Read more about handling dismissals
   result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
 ) {
    return false
  }
})
 }
```

Llamo a la función con el siguiente código:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.ClientScript.GetType(), "onLoad", "preguntar();", true);
```

Lo que quiero es saber si la función retorna "true" o "false". 
Y así poder hacer algo como esto

```
if(funcion==true){
 llamar_funcion_de_asp();
}else{
  --terminar_instruccion.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que tienes es hacer una llamada al método `__doPostback` en tu javascript:

```
if(funcion){           
     function () { __doPostBack("", idBoton); };
}
```

En IE hay un problema con este método y habría que añadir un `timeout` ([aquí](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/51c102be-88a7-4339-9d98-c069558be633/javascript-dopostback-recently-stopped-working-in-internet-explorer-114xxx?forum=iewebdevelopment) más info):

```
if(funcion){           
    setTimeout(function () { __doPostBack("", bId); }, 100);
}
```

Y en el `page_load` controlar con el `__EVENTARGUMENT` qué control ha sido el que ha lanzado el `postback` (aquí te paso con código en VB .Net)

```
Dim Parameter As String = Request("__EVENTARGUMENT")    
//¿El botón del sweetAlert contiene en el nombre "IMG"? En ese caso guardamos datos
If (Parameter.Contains("IMG")) Then 
     ///Guardar datos
End If
```

La otra opción (más limpia). Es hacer una llamada AJAX desde tu javascript al `backend` diciéndole los datos que quieres guardar:

```
swalWithBootstrapButtons({
  title: 'Desea guardar los registros?',
  text: "No podra cancelar la operacion",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, Guardar',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancelar!',
  reverseButtons: true
 }).then((result) => {

 if (result.value) {
   //llamada ajax al método de backend de guardardatos con los datos a guardar
 } ...
```

Comment: Gracias, ¿Cómo lo llamaría por AJAX?